# Iam creating a hangman game and has completed most of it but i cannot understand how to display the word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Iam creating a hangman game and has completed most of it but i cannot understand how to display the words in other form and to apply the letter when it is clicked on the screen keyboard which have been built by me.

heres the code:-

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: HeadingFont;
   src: url(DeliusUnicase-Bold.ttf);
  }
  
  /*body{display:none;}*/
  
  #playerInputOne , #playerInputTwo{
   height:30px;
   width:550px;
  }
  
  h2{font-family:HeadingFont , cursive;}
  
        #playerOne, #playerTwo , #wordOne, #wordHint {
   /*float:left;*/
   padding:3px;
   border:2px #07EBEF solid;
   height:20px;
   width:300px;
   border-radius: 10px 10px ;
  }
  
  
        #error1,#error2,#error3 , #error4 {
   color:#FF0004;
   /*float:left;*/
  }
  
  button , input{outline:none!important;}
  
  button:hover{background-color:#07E1E4;}
  
  button{
   box-shadow:none!important;
   margin-top:10px;
   background-color:#00FFFB;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   width:150px;
   text-align:;
   height:35px;
   border: none;
   font-weight:800;
   border-radius:5px;
   cursor:pointer;
   /*border:solid #00FFFB 2px;*/ 
  }
  
  
  
  #mainHeading{
   font-size:72px; 
  }
  
  #keyBoard{margin-left: 80px;}
  
  #enterWord{
   margin-top:10px;
  }
  
  #logo{width:600px;height:150px;}
        
  #enterButton{
   
   cursor:pointer!important;
   /*float:left;*/
  }
  
  .NewFont{font-family:HeadingFont , cursive;}
        
  #boxOfInput{width:100%;}
  
  #wrapper{
   width:470px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top:100px;
  }
  
  #lastLine{margin-left:30px;}
  
  #keyBoardKey{
   width:26px!important;
   font-family:HeadingFont , cursive!important;
   background-color:#FF9E00; 
  }
  
  #keyBoardKey:hover{background-color:#D18200;}
  
  #startTheGame{margin-left:200px;}
  
  .displayNone , .displayNoneTwo , .displayNoneOne , .displayNoneThree {display:none}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hangman</title>
</head>

<body style="">
    <div id="wrapper" class="starting">
        <center>
            <h2 id="mainHeading">Hangman</h2>
            <br>
            <h3>Made By Hasan Zain</h3>
        </center>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper" class="displayNoneOne">

        <div id="boxOfInput">

            <div id="playerInputOne"><span class="NewFont">Player 1 :  </span>
                <input type="text" id="playerOne" placeholder="  e.g. John" /><span id="error1"></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="playerInputTwo"><span class="NewFont">Player 2 :  </span>
                <input type="text" id="playerTwo" placeholder="  e.g. Sarah" /><span id="error2"></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick='checkingInput()' id="enterButton">Enter</button>
            <button onclick="StartSelector()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="displayNone">

        <h2>Enter the word</h2>

        <div id="theWordInput">
            <input type="text" id="wordOne" placeholder="  e.g. Pakistan" /><span id="error3"></span>
            <br>
            <button id="enterWord">Enter</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="wrapper" class="displayNone">
        <h2>Enter the Hint</h2>
        <input type="text" id="wordHint" placeholder="  e.g. Sport" /><span id="error4"></span>
        <br>
        <button id="EnterHint">Enter</button>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="displayNoneTwo">
        <button id="startTheGame">Start</button>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper" class="displayNoneThree">
        <div id="theWordGameBar">


        </div>
        <div id="keyBoard">
            <button id="keyBoardKey">A</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">B</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">C</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">D</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">E</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">F</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">G</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">H</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">I</button>
            <br>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">J</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">K</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">L</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">M</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">N</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">O</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">Q</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">R</button>
            <button id="keyBoardKey">S</button>
            <br>
            <div id="lastLine">
                <button id="keyBoardKey">T</button>
                <button id="keyBoardKey">U</button>
                <button id="keyBoardKey">V</button>
                <button id="keyBoardKey">W</button>
                <button id="keyBoardKey">X</button>
                <button id="keyBoardKey">Y</button>
                <button id="keyBoardKey">Z</button>
            </div>
            <br>


        </div>
    </div>



    <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.starting').fadeOut(4000, function() {
                $('.displayNoneOne').fadeIn(2000);
            })
        });

        var endInputOne;
        var endInputTwo;
        var playerOne;
        var playerTwo;

        function checkingInput() {

            playerOne = $('#playerOne').val();
            playerTwo = $('#playerTwo').val();

            if (playerOne == '') {

                $('#error1').html('*fill the input fields');
                endInputOne = false;


            } else {

                $('#error1').html('');
                endInputOne = true;

            }
            if (playerTwo == '') {

                $('#error2').html('*fill the input fields');
                endInputTwo = false;


            } else {

                $('#error2').html('');
                endInputTwo = true;

            }

        }

        var HangmanWord;
        var startOne;
        var startTwo;
        var start;
        var Word = $('#wordOne').val();
        var Hint = $('#wordHint').val();

        function StartSelector() {

            if (endInputOne == true) {
                var endOne = 1
            }
            if (endInputTwo == true) {
                endOne = endOne + 1;
            }
            if (endOne == 2) {
                $('#boxOfInput').fadeOut();
                $('.displayNone').fadeIn(2000);
                $('#enterWord').click(function() {

                    Word = $('#wordOne').val();

                    if (Word == '') {
                        $('#error3').html('*Fill in the Word!');
                        startOne = false;


                    } else {
                        $('#error3').html('');
                        startOne = true;

                    }


                });
            }
        }

        var theGameWord;

        $('#EnterHint').click(function() {

            Hint = $('#wordHint').val();

            if (Hint == '') {
                $('#error4').html("*Fill in the Word's Hint!");
                startTwo = false;


            } else {
                $('#error4').html('');
                startTwo = true;
            }

            if (startOne) {
                start = 1;
            } else {
                start = 0
            }
            if (startTwo) {
                start = start + 1;
            } else {
                start = 0;
            }
            if (start == 2) {
                $('.displayNoneTwo').fadeIn(2000);
            }



        });

        $('#startTheGame').click(function() {


            $('.displayNoneTwo').fadeOut((2000, function() {
                $('.displayNone').fadeOut(2000, function() {


                    $('.displayNoneThree').fadeIn(5000);



                });
            }));

            HangmanWord = Word.split("");
            theGameWord = HangmanWord.length;

            var Letters = ' _';
            var i;
            $('#theWordGameBar').html(HangmanWord);
            alert(HangmanWord)








        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First thing I notice is that you need to change your html. The ID's on your buttons (keyBoardKey) can't all be the same, that's bad html practice. There are ways you could retrieve which letter was clicked, but you won't be able to reference the element by ID.

Comment: You're missing the P.